# Size attribute with multiple quantities

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, extensions, module, quantity

I am trying to build a size attribute picker similar to the one on the Laura Ashley website: http://www.lauraashley.com/uk/invt/alexanderbl

[image: size picker with quantities]

Does any one have any information or ideas that I can use as a starting point for creating this? Are there any existing extensions or will this be a custom job - if so what would be the best practice for configuring this? A configurable product & custom attribute set?

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create this as a grouped product? That will give you (and the system) everything it expects, and you can add a little front end work to build the +/- quantity interface.